# Compare items of List<Object> to other elements in the list

Tags: c#, .net, list

I'm in need of a way to do what the title suggests.

The list consists of an object, which itself contains a list and an int.

I want to compare the ints of the objects and find which has the smallest int, then return this object.

At the moment I have come up with something like so, though I am struggling to proceed.

```
Object temp = new Object;
for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    for(int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; j++)
    {
        if(list[i].intVar < list[j].intVar)
        {
            temp = list[i];
        }
    }
}
return temp;
```

Thank you for any help
:)

Comment: can you show us how are you initializing and populating your list ?

Comment: Why is the variable `temp` of type `Object` when it should be the type of what `list` contains?

Comment: I think this question may be relevant> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290986/max-vs-orderbydescending-first

Comment: Right now you are just returning the last list[i].intVar < list[j].intVar.  What the title suggest is not clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question you want the smallest value of intVar out of the list.

```
 var smallestValue = list.SingleOrDefault(arg => arg.intVar== list.Min(arg => arg.intVar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregate to get the object with lowest int.

```
list.Aggregate((i, j) => i.intVar < j.intVar? i : j);
```

You will have to include System.Linq namespace to be able to use this extension method.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `list` contains some objects that has an `intVar` property,and you want to find the object that contains smallest `intVar`, you can use [`Enumerable.Min`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.min%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like this:

```
var minValue = list.Min(x => x.intVar);
return list.First(x => x.intVar == minValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just take the first element of the list when ordered by that field.  Linq works well for this:

```
  return list.OrderBy(x => x.intVar).First();
```